# Doctryne Manytomany composite key with join table

Tags: doctrine, many-to-many

ENTITY Utente:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Utente")
 */
class Utente extends BaseUser {



      /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sede", inversedBy="proprietario,codice")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="utente_sede")
     */
    protected $sedi;

       /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->sedi = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

ENTITY Sede:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Sede")
 */
class Sede {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Utente", mappedBy="sedi")
     **/
    protected $utenti;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->utenti = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }   

    /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="proprietario")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="proprietario", referencedColumnName="id_proprietario")
   * @ORM\Id 
   * */
    protected $proprietario;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=30)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @Assert\Regex("/^(0[0-9][0-9]|100)$/")
     */
    protected $codice;
```

I created the relationship ManyToMany (UTENTE <=> SEDE) with composite key:

Sedi table have primary key : proprietario,codice

Utente table have primary key: id

Next try command app\console" "--ansi" "doctrine:schema:update" "--force"

DOCTRYNE return this error.

[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
  Column name `id` referenced for relation from AppBundle\Entity\Utente towar
  ds AppBundle\Entity\Sede does not exist.

Comment: I have fixed one error:   
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sede", inversedBy="utenti")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="utente_sede",
      *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
      * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="sede_proprietario", referencedColumnName="proprietario")},
      * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="sede_codice", referencedColumnName="codice")})
     */
    protected $sedi;

Comment: [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE Sede ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8  
  AA94DEF3073F7C3 FOREIGN KEY (proprietario) REFERENCES Proprietario (id_prop  
  rietario)':                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'uniko.#sql-1d64_c6  
  ' (errno: 121)